# Recursive haskell and stack overflow

Tags: haskell

As someone relatively new to Haskell and functional programming, and coming mainly from a Python background, I'd like to know why the following function results in a stack overflow in Haskell, even if I use a very low number like 4, or 5 as the input variable, whereas the exact same function in Python can process an integer of 20 and up without overflowing.  Why is this so?

```
countStairs <0 = 0
countStairs 0 = 1
countStairs n = countStairs(n-1) + countStairs(n-2) + countStairs(n-3)
```

I've read other responses on Haskell and stack overflows that address code optimization and solving specific overflowing code, whereas I'm interested in understanding the specifc reason for the difference in how the two languages handle recursion here, or more generally why the Haskell code results in a stack overflow.

EDIT: I didn't include the full python code because this is my first question in Stack Overflow and I'm struggling to figure out how to get my Python to format properly (nice welcome from some of you, btw).  Here it is, poor formatting and all, but the Python as written does work properly with the integer 20, whereas my undoubtedly poor Haskell has not.  I've edited the Haskell code to show the corresponding code I originally omitted.  I thought I was including the relevant recursive part, but obviously I was wrong to omit the base case.  Still, as written, my Haskell stack overflows and my Python doesn't, and I'm still interested in learning why.  Even though I don't come from a programming background, I really like learning Haskell and was just trying to learn some more.  Thanks to those who tried to address the question in spite of my incomplete question.

```
def countStairs(n):
    if n < 0:
        return 0
    elif n == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return countStairs(n-1) + countStairs(n-2) + countStairs(n-3)

myint = int(raw_input("Please enter an integer: "))
print countStairs(myint)
```

Comment: Python can run an infinite recursion without overflowing its stack, and in finite time??

Comment: @Rahul: Well, it already has antigravity. Performing infinite computations can't be that much harder.

Comment: @EricS.Bullington Since it is a common "next mistake", please note that there is [no automatic memoizing](http://hpaste.org/55915) going on either.  OTOH as the link shows, it isn't hard to add.

Comment: -1 for not reporting what the `exact same` python program outputs for `countStairs 20`

Comment: [Exact same program in python](http://ideone.com/vPfFx) overflows. Huge stack trace is super helpful. ;)

Comment: @Dan, thank you for setting this straight.

Comment: @Eric, I've corrected your python formatting... Formatting code in SO is as simple as indenting it four spaces.  There's also a friendly button to help you with it (just select your code, and click the `{}` button.

Comment: Thanks, Adam.  I was trying to use the four spaces, but for some reason it still wasn't formatting correcting.  Could it be because I use spaces instead of tabs to whitespace format my Python?  In any case, thanks again.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Another way to add a terminating condition is to use a guard (this also addresses the `<= 2` condition Corbin mentioned:

```
countStairs n | n > 0 = countStairs(n-1) + countStairs(n-2) + countStairs(n-3)
              | otherwise = 1
```

**Update**

Your updated Haskell example doesn't work because you misunderstand a how pattern matching works.  You were expecting it to work like a guard (seeing as you tried to provide a boolean expression `< 0` in a pattern match), however, that version of your function never matches (when you call the countStairs function).  Consider this example:

```
countStairs < 0 = "Matched '< 0'"
countStairs   0 = "Matched '0'"
countStairs   n = "Matched n"

main = do
    putStrLn $ countStairs (-1)  -- outputs: "Matched n"
    putStrLn $ countStairs 0     -- outputs: "Matched 0"
    putStrLn $ countStairs 20    -- outputs: "Matched n"
```

The interesting thing here is that your function actually compiles.  To find out why, load the above code into ghci and type `:browse`.  This will give you a list of the functions you've defined in this module.  You should see something like this:

```
(Main.<) :: Num a => t -> a -> [Char]
countStairs :: Num a => a -> [Char]
main :: IO ()
```

You've got `countStairs` and `main` which both make sense.  But you've also got this function called `Main.<`.  What is this? You've redefined the `<` function in this module!  In case you're not familiar, you can define infix functions (like `+`, `<`, `>`, etc.) like so:

```
infix <
a < b = True

-- also defined as
(<) a b = True
```

Normally, you need that `infix FUNCTION_NAME` to indicate your function is infix.  But.. prelude already defines `<` as an infix function, therefore, you didn't need to, and instead just gave your own definition of `<`.

Now, lets rearrange our `countStairs < 0 = "Matched '< 0'"` like we did with `a < b`, and you get this:

```
(<) countStairs 0 = "Matched '< 0'"
```

In this function, `countStairs` is actually the first argument to your `<` function.

Here's one more example to drive home the point.  Try running `1 < 0` in ghci (with your module still loaded).  Here's what you'll get:

```
*Main> 1 < 0

<interactive>:1:3:
    Ambiguous occurrence `<'
    It could refer to either `Main.<', defined at foo.hs:3:13
                          or `Prelude.<', imported from Prelude
```

Normally, you'd get `False`, but in this case, ghci doesn't know if it should use your function (since `<` is just a regular function, not a special syntax) or the built-in (Prelude) version of `<`.

Long story short... use guards (or `case`, or `if`) for boolean tests, not pattern matches.

Comment: Ah, was not aware of that syntax (my haskell knowledge is very limited :p).  I quite like that syntax ([and C A McCann's] and how it captures more cases than just n = 0) better than my own answer.  +1 :)

Comment: @Corbin: That syntax is called "guards", and the bit after the `|` can be an arbitrary boolean expression. Oh, and `otherwise` is just a cute way of writing `True` that the standard library provides.

Comment: Haskell is on my list of languages to learn, but have only looked at it very briefly :).

Comment: @Corbin: You should spend some time learning it when you can; I've enjoyed it immensely, myself. And I hear the community tends to be pretty helpful, especially on Stack Overflow. ;]

Comment: Ah, I know a bit of Scheme, but have never messed with Haskell.  I find functional programming to be enthralling though and want to learn more in the future. I shall keep your suggestion in mind :).

Comment: Thanks, I should have included my full code.  I had a terminating condition, or what I thought was one, but I used pattern matching instead of guards.  Obviously, there's some reason that doesn't work (if it's scope I'm not sure I understand why).  BTW, Haskell is great  -- and I'm finally using map and reduce comfortably in my Python.  I look forward to gaining enough understanding of Haskell to where I can use it fluently.

Comment: @EricS.Bullington I've updated my answer to help explain why your haskell code (without the guards) didn't work as expected.  Please let me know if it makes sense.

Comment: @hammar: `infix` alone is also a valid fixity declaration. It means the operator doesn't associate either way and can't be mixed with anything else of the same precedence.

Comment: Thanks so much for the very detailed explanation!  It's all very clear now.  It's actually kind of funny how my original program ended up compiling.  A big thank you as well for introducing me to `:browse` -- very cool.

Answer (score 8):

Not very familiar with haskell, but it looks like there's no terminating condition. I believe that will keep going with n approaching negative infinity.

Try something like:

```
countStairs 0 = 1
countStairs n = countStairs(n-1) + countStairs(n-2) + countStairs(n-3)
```

That will mean that countStairs(0) = 1.

You might need to worry about negatives too if you ever plan on calling countStairs(n) | n <= 2.

Comment: One needs three consecutive base cases or it will become an infinite recursion.

Comment: Thanks, Corbin.  My full program had a terminating condition but I made the (now) obvious mistake of omitting it.  See above for my original code, which still stack overflows.

Answer (score 8):

Using this:

```
countStairs n | n <= 0 = 1
countStairs n = countStairs(n-1) + countStairs(n-2) + countStairs(n-3)
```

Gives me this in GHCi:

```
∀x. x ⊢ countStairs 20
289329
```

...in about two seconds. So yes, Corbin seems to be correct.

Comment: Thanks for your serious response.  Please see my edited code above in response to your comment about antigravity. Looking at your response, I re-coded my Haskell above, but with guards like you used instead of the kind of pattern matching I used, and it worked.  I'm left wondering why.

Comment: @EricS.Bullington: See Adam Wagner's answer--you were unintentionally re-defining `<`, rather than expressing a condition like you wanted. Pattern matching only works for exact matches. In this case, guards are what you wanted in the first place.

Comment: thanks for the explanation.  Yes, I was confusing guards and pattern matching.  I'll be careful now to use pattern matching on with exact matches.